# 3D image plotting

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am facing a problem doing some animation for a assignment in matlab

Let say that for instance I have a matrix 3D where the last index determine the color and the the others are determining the x,y,z coordinates.

a(:,:,1,1) =

```
0.9124    0.8790    0.8823
0.3242    0.7791    0.4257
0.2905    0.3944    0.4664
```

a(:,:,2,1) =

```
0.4249    0.0956    0.4965
0.4552    0.7335    0.2597
0.6954    0.1300    0.5917
```

a(:,:,3,1) =

```
0.2276    0.1832    0.1372
0.9551    0.6242    0.1889
0.0630    0.2914    0.9566
```

a(:,:,1,2) =

```
0.2966    0.0043    0.2240
0.2372    0.0782    0.6953
0.6602    0.3096    0.7002
```

a(:,:,2,2) =

```
0.8518    0.5309    0.3834
0.5591    0.8589    0.5954
0.5703    0.4463    0.3050
```

a(:,:,3,2) =

```
0.1011    0.6432    0.6211
0.3719    0.7767    0.2791
0.2222    0.4300    0.4780
```

a(:,:,1,3) =

```
0.3147    0.1443    0.7440
0.8272    0.0683    0.8357
0.7432    0.5321    0.7207
```

a(:,:,2,3) =

```
0.8876    0.8820    0.7249
0.1629    0.4620    0.8836
0.2012    0.1870    0.7980
```

a(:,:,3,3) =

```
0.8430    0.5304    0.7167
0.5380    0.8433    0.8627
0.2096    0.2153    0.4713
```

Now I need a 3D image where all the point should be like the result we get when we use imagesc matlab command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display slice #3 (z=3):

```
zind = 3;
imagesc(squeeze(a(:,:,zind,:)))
```